# Перенаправление, замена ссылок в IIS

Tags: iis

У меня на IIS установлена wiki, она откывается по адресу wiki.mysite.ru/wiki/Wiki_startpage. Только если полностью ввести такой адрес в строке. Как сделать, чтобы можно было ввести wiki.mysite.ru и автоматически открывалась страничка wiki.mysite.ru/wiki/Wiki_startpage. Так же работает и на сайте википедии, вводишь ru.wikipedia.org а открывается страница [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

Нашел, в функциях web сайта, есть раздел Http Redirect, там можно настроить страничку переадресации